# How to detect if user removed the app from Facebook via app settings or changed Facebook password and revisits the app

Tags: java, android, facebook

I have an Android app that is using Facebook SDK. Currently running into the problem where the user is still able to access my app after changing his Facebook password or deleting my app using Facebook App settings.

In my app I am checking the Facebook access token and it always seems to be eligible. Why the token status does not update? How to update it?

Here is the method I use to verify access token:

```
public static AuthStatus checkAuthStatus() {
    AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();

    if (accessToken != null && !accessToken.isExpired()) return AuthStatus.SIGNED_IN_WITH_FACEBOOK;
    else return AuthStatus.SIGNED_OUT;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out how to check if token is eligible.

```
AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                accessToken,
                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                        if (response.getError() == null) {
                            // token is eligible
                        } else {
                            // token is not eligible
                        }
                    }
                });
```